# Trouble Left Aligning Images for HTML Email

Tags: html, css, html-email

New to coding and learning how to create HTML email. I picked a random email and trying to replicate it.

I am trying to align the google image next to the Apple Play store image and have the social media icons all be to the left.

I have searched W3, Google and Stack Overflow. I've tried to add padding.

Thank you for your assistance.

```
                         <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="/img/applestorelogo.png" width="auto" height="24" style=" display: inline-block;" alt="applestorelogo"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="/img/googlestore.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="googlestore"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><img src="/img/fb.png" width="auto" height="24"  alt="facebook"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><img src="/img/IG.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="instagram"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><img src="/img/twitter.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="twitter"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Below is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8b9B.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use only three `<td>`.

The following is an idea for your scenario. You may need to change width according to your layout:

```
<table border="1" style="width:50%">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; width: 5%;">
        <img src="/img/applestorelogo.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="applestorelogo"/>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;width: 5%;">
        <img src="/img/googlestore.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="googlestore"/>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="/img/fb.png" width="auto" height="24"  alt="facebook"/>  
        <img src="/img/IG.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="instagram"/>  
        <img src="/img/twitter.png" width="auto" height="24" alt="twitter"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Khurram. I was able to figure out what I could not get the two images to align next to each other. I needed a display: inline-block on the original table. Now I need to address the social media icons to be on one side and apple/google play store on the other. I think I will need to create two separate tables.

Comment: You might be able to work around via inline-block. But I would suggest using <div> more often. With <div>, your layout will be loaded much faster. Anyhow, try to reduce <td> for alignment purpose like I have given example, try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr style="display: inline-block;">
            <td>
                <img style="border: 2px red solid" src="/img/applestorelogo.png" alt="applestorelogo"/>
            </td>
            <td>
             <img style="border: 2px red solid" src="/img/googlestore.png" alt="googlestore"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img style="border: 2px red solid" src="/img/fb.png" alt="facebook"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img style="border: 2px red solid" src="/img/IG.png" alt="instagram"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img style="border: 2px red solid" src="/img/twitter.png" alt="twitter"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Disregard the borders. I was using it to troubleshoot.